# How to use SparkSession inside a map function?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v.
I have a scenario where I need to create a tempTableOrView inside a map function.

```
sparkSession  = //create a sparkSession


Dataset<?> unionDs  =//create an empty  

countriesListDs.map( country -> {
  String tableName  = "table_" + country ;
   sparkSession.createTempTableOrView(tableName  );

   resultDs  = //do aggregations on this table 

     unionDs  =  unionDs.union(resultDs)  

sparkSession.catalog.dropTable(tableName  )

);

unionDs.writeToFile;
```

Is it possible to access the sparkSession inside the map function ?

Please advice me

Comment: Did you try and what was the result?

Comment: why are you creating a tempview inside the loop?

Comment: also why are you creating tempview per country ? what exactly your use case here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to access the sparkSession inside the map function ?

No. It's not possible (and would make no sense since they're to describe distributed computation not be part thereof).

SparkSession, like SparkContext, are only available on the driver while `map` works on executors.

> I need to create a tempTableOrView inside a map function.

Inside `map`? Not possible (and does not make much sense since it's row-based).

You should `map` and then `createOrReplaceTempView`.

Comment: No. In `map` you're on executors and you've got no need to `createOrReplaceTempView` (which can only be executed on the driver).

Comment: sir how r u doing , sir can you advice on this use-case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524489/can-this-use-case-be-done-by-lag-any-other-function-of-spark-if-so-how-can-this